# From the html/jsp page, how to access Javascript file which is in the firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In firefox extension,

I have loaded web page using

```
    <browser src="www.abc.com/index.html">
```

Is it possible access js file which is in the extension from index.html ?

could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The extension have to set the contentaccessible flag to yes. Please check this:

[Chrome Registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#contentaccessible)